# How to explain mathematically Borel's Paradox??

Tags: probability-theory

I found conditional density for a longitude and latitude.

And, I could check that conditional density for a latitude is not uniform but

conditional density for a longitude is uniform.

Could you explain about reason by considering definition of conditional expectation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The densities you mention are related to uniform density on $S^2$ with respect to area.

The area enclosed by two nearby meridian lines only depends on the angle between them (measured at the poles). It is then obvious that the probability density $f_\Phi(\phi)$ of the geographical longitude is the constant ${1\over2\pi}$.

On the other hand the area enclosed between two nearby latitude circles not only depends on the width $\Delta\theta$ of the enclosed zone, but also on the length of these  circles, and is  $\approx 2\pi \cos\theta\>\Delta\theta$, whereby $\theta=0$ at the equator. It follows that the density $f_\Theta(\theta)$ of the geographical latitude comes to
$$f_\Theta(\theta)={\cos\theta\over2}\qquad\bigl(-{\pi\over2}\leq\theta\leq{\pi\over2}\bigr)\ .$$